# How to export a list of restaurants from yelp

Tags: api

Let's say I want to quickly get a list of all the restaurants around a certain location from yelp, and then put that list of results into a word or excel document.

Is there anyway to do this without manually copying and pasting every entry? I'd assume it'd involve using the Yelp API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this easily with the Yelp API. For example

```
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=restaurants&location=San+Francisco
```

See the [API documentation](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api) for more details on the `location` parameter:

> location
>
> Specifies the combination of "address, neighborhood, city, state or
>   zip, optional country" to be used when searching for businesses.